# How different nohup & or daemon (on uwsgi for restful server)?

Tags: python, linux, apache, server, uwsgi

I am using uwsgi for restful server.

Type this in shell `nohup /home/ubuntu/anaconda3/envs/py37/bin/uwsgi --ini uwsgi.ini &`

OK, now it works when shell closed.

however ,,,,, is it ok for long time use???

Normally i use apache + uwsgi for web server as daemon, but what I need now is just internal restful server.

It looks satisfying my purpose,but is there any problem to continue using??

I want to know the difference of daemon and shell command.

Comment: Self-daemonizing programs are not considered best practice in modern use either. The right thing is a supervised service that will be automatically restarted by process supervision system when it fails.

Comment: In most modern Linux distros, that role is provided by [systemd](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Systemd); on MacOS it's provided by [launchd](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Launchd). If you're building your own distro or embedded system, I would encourage you to also consider [runit](http://smarden.org/runit/) or [s6](https://skarnet.org/software/s6/), which have much more minimalist design, and consequently less to go wrong.

Comment: Beyond that, I'd argue that this question isn't topical here. [unix.se] is a better place for questions about system administration tools and techniques; Stack Overflow is narrowly focused on questions about how one writes code, and tries hard to avoid topics that are likely to be contentious (and while consensus that process supervision is the right thing is near-universal, consensus on which process supervision systems are best is anything but!)

Comment: Immediately, though: The big problem with starting something with nohup (other than the problems innate and specific to nohup -- the hardcoded use of `nohup.out`, the use of a nonstandard tool when bash itself can do effectively all of its job, etc) is that if your server reboots due to power flux, or the process has a memory leak and crashes, your service is down. That's never a place you want to be.

Comment: Most process supervision systems are also bundled with tools to do some kind of log rotation and management, so you can quickly find the logs for what happened at a specific time, and prevent those logs from eating so much disk space that your services start failing. Roll your own thing with nohup, and you're on your own for that. More complex supervision tools also let you specify dependencies -- "thing A needs database server B to be up before it can work, and if the database server restarts, you'll need to restart the web server too".

Comment: ...again, though -- wrong place for the question, generally off-topic here, and almost certainly has duplicates already in the knowledge base *both* at [unix.se] and [Server Fault](https://serverfault.com/).

Comment: Thank you very much for your explanation. I understand how shell command is not good for service.

Comment: And also I will post this kind of topics to Unix & Linux. Thank you very much for your help.

Comment: And for my problem I will use `uwsgi` with `daemonize` option.

Comment: If your operating system has systemd (like Fedora and CentOS and new Ubuntu do) or Upstart (like older Ubuntu does), I would strongly urge you to use that instead.

Comment: See https://uwsgi-docs.readthedocs.io/en/latest/Systemd.html documenting how to set up uwsgi as a service with systemd.